# Kotlin AAR library w/ proguard: how to keep extension methods?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm writing a new Kotlin library module to add commonly used classes and extension methods.  I'm compiling each extensions file (eg BitmapExtensions.kt) into a single file called 'Extensions' using `JvmMultifileClass`:

```
@file:JvmName("Extensions")
@file:JvmMultifileClass

fun Bitmap.crop(cropRect: Rect) = ...
```

As a part of our company's IP policy I need to obfuscate the library via proguard *before* it makes it to any consumer project.  I therefore need a proguard rule to keep these extension methods so that they are not thrown away.

At first glance the below seems to work, inspecting the generated AAR's classes.jar shows that the extension methods still exist and their internals have been obfusecated.  But when actually compiling in a consumer project, I get unresolved references to any extension method I've referenced.

```
-keepclassmembernames class mycompany.kotlin.util.Extensions {
    <methods>;
}
```

When I disable minification, the project builds correctly.

How can I obfuscate my library and keep my kotlin extensions?

edit: It appears that using `keep` on the entire package, and even specifying `-dontshrink` is not enough.  The methods simply cannot be referenced in the consumer app.

edit2: I believe I have narrowed this down to the `.kotlin_module` file under /META-INF/ being removed when `minifyEnabled=true`.  This appears to be the ONLY difference between my minified and non-minified classes.jar.  Something is removing this file... or preventing its generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded to gradle 4.1 milestone 1.  The `.kotlin_module` metadata file is no longer being stripped when `minifyEnabled=true` and my consumer app can now use extension methods from the lib correctly.

Comment: Hi, Tom! It seems that it is still an issue. Would you please describe all the steps that you did for your extensions to be seen?

Comment: Also thanks for your post) at least my kotlin file is now seen after obfuscation after I've added @file:JvmName("Extensions")

Comment: edit: JvmName only is not enough in order to see Kotlin file, also JvmMultifileClass should be added. And it only is visible in java

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I found out that the problem is with R8, android.enableR8 = false fixed the problem

Comment: No worries! Good to hear you found a solution. We ended up dropping obfuscation from our lib as it was just producing too many odd issues like this.

Comment: Will keep that in mind) Update: It was R8 bug that is fixed in the latest version 2.1.75. You can either add this - "classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:2.1.75" on top of gradle build tools dependency  or upgrade gradle build tools to 4.1.1+

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still struggling with this in 2022. What helped me was to intentionally merge the `.kotlin_module` to the library by adding this snippet to the library's module `build.gradle`:

```
packagingOptions {
    merge "/META-INF/*.kotlin_module"
}
```

EDIT:
Turned out that the problem was caused by having the kotlin meta info excluded from the build result, which I didn't notice initially, so what you really have to do is finding and removing the following code:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude "/META-INF/*.kotlin_module"
    }
```